# Surge confirmation href == null

Tags: uber-api

Trying to estimate ride , but surge confirmation href equals null. What should i do to order ride?

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpesB.png)

In docs (developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/…) surge_confirmaion_href equals to "https://api.uber.com/v1/surge-confirmations/7d604f5e", but i have surge_confirmation_href : null (you can see it in attached screenshot)

Can be a reason, that in selected location uber works for a week ?

Comment: Could you add the code you are having problem with to the question? It will make it easier for others to get a quick overview of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case if surge pricing is currently in effect for specific product you will get error response when you try to create new ride request:

- **409 Conflict**

In that case your response will have following info:

```html
"surge_confirmation": {
         "href": "https:\/\/api.uber.com\/v1\/surge-confirmations\/e100a670",
         "surge_confirmation_id": "e100a670",
         "multiplier": 1.4,
         "expires_at": 1459191276
      }
```

So you will need to use "surge_confirmation_id": "e100a670" and make another POST request to "POST /v1.2/requests" in order to create a valid ride request.

Comment: Have you seen response screen? There "surge_confirmation_id" equals to null

Comment: If you do not get **"surge_confirmation_id"**  and **"surge_confirmation_href"** in that case there is no **Surge Pricing** for your estimate.  For more info please check: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/references/api/v1.2/requests-estimate-post#ride-request-estimate